# DOM error while using .classList.add method

Tags: javascript

So when I'm trying to add two classes to my elemeny by this code

```
var curr_class = document.getElementById(hover_start).className
document.getElementById(hover_start).classList.add("cell-red",curr_class)
```

I have this error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('1 cell-red') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.

I don't see any incorrect white space in here

Comment: what is hover_start? is it ID of the DOM element?

Answer (score 12):

What seems to be the issue is that `curr_class` is a string containing a space

According to the doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList

You should add the class one by one.

Note also that what your code does is : it takes the class of an element and adds it to the same element so nothing usefull

Comment: The solution works, eventhough it's link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList doesn't say that we must add class one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a space in your class name: `1 cell-red` between `1` and `cell-red`.

One solution would be to add the classes one by one:

```
myElement.classList.add('1');
myElement.classList.add('cell-red');
```

Answer (score 1):

@CharybdeBE is correct

Alternatively you could separate the classes with commas inside the add function.

For example:

```
myElement.classList.add('class1', 'class2', 'class3');
```

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs when the class is an empty string. Therefore it is necessary to:

1. trim the string before passing it in (since `DOMTokenList` will try to trim and error)
2. check if the string is empty before calling `add()`
3. split the string by spaces
4. spread the array of strings as params

Example usage from a function used to convert an `img` to a `canvas`:

```js
const ns = {
  canvas: (o = {}) => {
    o.img ??= new Image();
    o.cls ??= ''; //can pass in class string with spaces
    o.w ??= 100;
    o.h ??= 100;
    o.canvas ??= document.createElement("canvas");
    o.canvas.width = o.w;
    o.canvas.height = o.h;
    o.ctx = o.canvas.getContext('2d', {
      willReadFrequently: true
    });
    o.ctx.drawImage(o.img, 0, 0, o.w, o.h);
    o.cls.trim(); //trims the whitespace before DOMTokenList errors
    o.cls && o.canvas.classList.add(...o.cls.split(' ')); //string is not empty, split by whitespace, spread as params
    return o.canvas;
  }
}
```